# Error executing task CreateEmbeddedResources: Task does not have property "BundleResources" defined

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, 64-bit, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am converting an existing Xamarin.iOS project to unified api (64 bit compatible), within my project a 3rd party project exists and after converting to unified I am facing a build/compile time error saying like "Error: Error executing task CreateEmbeddedResources: Task does not have property "BundleResources" defined (3rdPartyLibraryiOS)"

I have tried applying http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/115358/#Comment_115358 solution, which worked for many but unfortunately Its not working for me, If I try this solution then my 3rd party project is getting treated as not an unified one!, If I revert then this error will occur. Got stuck hear.

Any help in resolving this is much appreciated in advance.